# How to bind the value in p-autoComplete in angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a search box with p-autocomplete. When I search for the value, the value is getting displayed in the suggestion.

[image]

I am trying to display the selected value from the suggestion in the p-autocomplete box. But when I select I am getting [Object Object]. I am new to angular. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

**HTML CODE**

```
  <p-autoComplete id="dataCmpnyAuto" 
      name="dataCmpnyAuto" 
      [suggestions]="dataCmpnyAutoList" 
      (onKeyUp)="startSearch($event.target.value)"
       dropdownIcon="pi pi-angle-down" 
       (onSelect)="getCompanyList($event)"
       formControlName="dataCmpnyAuto">

       <ng-template let-i pTemplate="item">
          <div class="country-item">
            <h6>{{ i.name}}</h6>
            <div>{{ i.id}}</div>
          </div>
       </ng-template>  </p-autoComplete>
```

testComponent.ts

```
startSearch(name:any){
let Type = 0
this.pagesService.getCompanyAutoCmpList(Type, name).subscribe((results) =>{
  const responseData = results.success
  if(responseData && responseData.length>0){
    this.dataCmpnyAutoList = responseData
  }

})}
```

Comment: Please share stackblitz with issue replicate and screenshots on what is going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeNG [does not support](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2242) selected item templates in the single selection mode. There's a workaround though. You can control the *text* of the selected item template:

```html
<p-autoComplete [field]="getSelectedItemName" ...></p-autoComplete>
```

```js
getSelectedItemName(item: { id: number; name: string }): string {
  return item.name;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo-pwtfhj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Great answer thanks. It works. But if I want to display both Id and Name what can we do in that case

Comment: You could do something like `return item.id + ' - ' + item.name` but unfortunately this does not support HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display name and Id to your users, then I suggest to prepare your objects array match intended output from your function that fetches data from api

In your html just add `field` as per documentation  [read here][1]

```
<p-autoComplete  
 [suggestions]="dataCmpnyAutoList" 
(completeMethod)="....."
field="combineNameId" ...>
</p-autoComplete>
```

And in your  Ts file , map array list to add `combinedNameId` key in your object

```
startSearch(name:any){
let Type = 0
this.pagesService.getCompanyAutoCmpList(Type, name).subscribe((results) {
  const responseData = results.success
  if(responseData && responseData.length>0){
    this.dataCmpnyAutoList = responseData .map((item:any)=>({
   ...item,
    combinedNameId: item.name + ' ' + item.id

        })
  }

})}
```

OR: If you don't want to manipulate your array of data from the api , you could achieve this using ng-template pTemplate="item" of p-autocomplete component, just modify the p-autocomplete as follows:

```
<p-autoComplete  
     [suggestions]="dataCmpnyAutoList" 
    (completeMethod)="....."
    >
    
          <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
            <div
              class="surface-overlay w-9 overflow-hidden text-overflow-ellipsis"
            >
            <span>{{ item.name | uppercase }}-{{item.id}}</span>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
    </p-autoComplete>
```

> And your ts file

```
 startSearch(name: any) {
 let Type = 0

this.pagesService.getCompanyAutoCmpList(Type, name).subscribe((results) {

    this.dataCmpnyAutoList = results?.success
  

}
```

}
[1]: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/autocomplete